# Total potential energy and equilibrium

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, stress-strain

Suppose a deformable body is under an external load. If there is no inclusion of gravity. When the body reach an equilibrium state, will the total potential energy be equal to zero? The total potential energy is:

$$\Pi = \text{Internal Strain Energy}  + \text{Potential Energy} $$

And we say that equilibrium is when the derivative is zero or the total energy unchanging?

$$\frac{\Delta \Pi}{\Delta u}=0$$

But at a equilibrium for a conservative system, shouldn't the work done by the internal strain energy and external work be the same and cancel each other?

If so why do we say a stable equilibrium state has lesser total potential energy than other states (neutral or unstable)

Comment: Shouldn't both works be the same even when it isn't in equilibrium due to the conservation of energy?

Comment: Yes. But with other stability states like (neutral, unstable,stable) , how do we say we take the minimum potential energy out of all. Won't they all be in equilibrium?

Comment: Can you specify your setting a bit better? What exactly do you mean by external "load"? Are you talking about an elastic body, or do you take plastic deformations into account?

Comment: By external load, I mean some static type of external force. Let us say the body is elastic? In most mechanic books, they simply just state it this way that a deformable body under external loading, so that how I also put it. I'm also interested if plastic deformations also occur? I've been struggling trying to just understand this.

Comment: Alan, if you want a specific user to see a comment, tag them using '@username'

Comment: When you determine the work done on a body, you only include the work done by external forces.  So there is no cancellation.  What you have asked is equivalent to asking if action-reaction pairs cancel so there is never any force acting on a body.

Comment: I understand that. I'ts just at a deformable state which is in equilibrium . Those equilibrium states can be under stable or unstable form. So you're asked to find an equilibrium state where the total potential energy is minimized and to check the second derivative. So I'm just not sure where to think beyond that. @ChesterMiller